# Generating divs each with random class from the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble figuring out why following function is not achieving what it should:

```
function example() {
    var $element;
    var rndClass;
    var classesArr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    var container = $('.container');

    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        rndClass = Math.floor(Math.random()*classesArr.length);
        $element = $('</div>', {'class': 'card '+classesArr[rndClass]+''});
        $(container).append($element);
    }

}
```

In a nutshel I want to generate 10 divs each having a class of card + another class from classesArr (array) that is selected randomly and after append each of these divs to a container div, so far nothing seems to be happening. Here is a jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u5LLx8gq/4/

As a sidenote, it would be great if you guys could suggest a better way to get these random clases, so there should be more or less equal amount of these used in 10 divs.

Comment: You have typo in code, </div> should be <div>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get more or less an even number of class types while still selecting at random you can do something like this.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var classes = ['card-1', 'card-2', 'card-3'],
      classes_cpy = classes.slice(),
      i = 10,
      ran;

  for (; i--;) {
    ran = (Math.random() * classes_cpy.length) | 0;
    $('body').append(
      $('<div>', {
        'text': i,
        // remove and return a random string from the array
        'class': 'card ' + classes_cpy.splice(ran, 1)[0]
      })
    );
    // reload the array with values when it is empty
    if (classes_cpy.length === 0) {
      classes_cpy = classes.slice();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.card-1 { background-color:green; }
.card-2 { background-color:red; }
.card-3 { background-color:pink; }
.card { border:1px solid white; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Whats the for (; i--;) bit?

Comment: It just counts down to 0.

Comment: @Ilja I was going to answer your previous question, I was already to post an answer then it was deleted. I still had the code open in another browser tab.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was about to post my code in and jsFidle crashed on me, so I started new one.

Answer (score 1):

Updated

Try

```js
var primaryClass = "card";
var additionalClasses = ["one", "two", "three"];
var clones = $.map(Array(additionalClasses.length + 1), function() {
  return [$.extend([], additionalClasses)]
});
var i = 0;
var collection = Array(10);
var elems = $.map(collection, function(el, idx) {
  i = !!clones[i].length ? i : i + 1;
  return $("<div />", {
    "text": idx,
    "class": primaryClass
        + " "
        + primaryClass
        + "-" 
        + clones[i].splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * clones[i].length), 1)
  })[0]
});

console.log(elems);

$("body").append(elems);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Super neat, but it doesn't address this portion of the question: *there should be more or less equal amount of these used in 10 divs*

Comment: Not going to lie I had to `console.log(JSON.stringify(clones));` at the top of the map function to figure out how this works. This is a pretty cool implementation +1.

Comment: @robbmj fwiw, at `clones` , `return [additionalClasses.slice()]` could be substituted for `return [$.extend([], additionalClasses)]`

Answer (score 0):

I think this

```
$(function(){
    function example() {
     var $element = null;
     var rndClass = 0;
     var classesArr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
     var $container = $('.container');
     var MAX_ELEMENTS = 10;

    for(;MAX_ELEMENTS--;) {
        rndClass = Math.floor(Math.random()*classesArr.length);
        $element = $('<div></div>', {
            'class': 'card '+ classesArr[rndClass],
            'text': MAX_ELEMENTS
        });
        $container.append($element);
    }

}

example();
});
```